# PHP PDO multi-column search

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to create a search in PHP using PDO. It has two input fields. Currently If I remove one of the fields and its associated PHP code it retrieves the data from the database. But when both are there, the "joke" input field content only limits the data if "author" input is present.

this is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <form action="search.php" method="get">
        <label for="text">Joke</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text">

        <label>Author</label>
        <label for="author">author</label>
        <select name="author" id="author">
            <option>select</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-orange">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is the PHP:

```
<?php       
    $query = "SELECT * FROM joke WHERE TRUE";
    $bind = Array();

    if ($_GET)
    {
        if ($_GET["text"] && $_GET["text"] != "") {
            $query .= " and joke_text like :joke_text";
            $bind[':joke_text'] = "%{$_GET['text']}%";
        }

        if ($_GET["author"] && $_GET["author"] != "") {
         $query .= " and author_id = :author_id";
            $bind[':author_id'] = "{$_GET['author']}";
        }

        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($bind);
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

        var_dump($rows);
    }
?>
```

I don't get any errors that are present.

Could someone kindly take a look?

Comment: What `$dbConnection->errorInfo()` returns?

Comment: AFAIK it should be `$bind['joke_text']` instead of `$bind[':joke_text']`

Comment: So when it's not working, what's the var_dump (or print_r) of $_GET?

Comment: @marian0 errorInfo() returns: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) array(0) { }

Comment: @MacPrawn returns: array(0) { }

Comment: @Dudley Students var_dump($_GET) returns array(0) {} ?

Comment: @MacPrawn, sorry read it wrong. this is the output: array(2) { ["text"]=> string(7) "chicken" ["author"]=> string(6) "select" }

Comment: So as you see, "author" will have the value "select" - which I doubt matches any data in your database... Try replacing `<option>select</option>` in your html with `<option value="">select</option>` to force "author" to be empty if the user doesn't pick one from the drop down menu...

Comment: @MacPrawn yes that was it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The best pattern here is to accumulate a list of conditions and collapse them with `implode` when finished:

```
$bind = [ ];
$conds = [ ];

if ($_GET)
{
    if ($_GET["text"] && $_GET["text"] != "") {
      $conds[] = "joke_text like :joke_text";
      $bind[':joke_text'] = "%{$_GET['text']}%";
    }

    if ($_GET["author"] && $_GET["author"] != "") {
      $conds[] = "author_id = :author_id";
      $bind[':author_id'] = "{$_GET['author']}";
    }

    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($query . ($conds ? " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conds) : "");
    $stmt->execute($bind);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    var_dump($rows);
}
```

That way the `WHERE` clause only appears if there's something important to do and the `AND` statements are introduced only if necessary.